# Intent from Service to Activity Issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send extras to my MainActivity once a user opens a notification. In my `sendNotification` method I have the following code

```
intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
intent.putExtras(extras);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);
```

In my MainActivity I accept the intent and get the extras like so:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
        System.out.println("MainActivity intent extras: " + getIntent().getExtras().toString());
        if(extras.getBoolean("fromNotification"))
            if(extras.getInt("not_id", 0) == 1) // Voicemail
                switchContent(new VoicemailFragment());
            else if (extras.getInt("not_id", 0) == 2) // Missed Call 
                switchContent(new RecentFragment());
            else
                switchContent(new MainDashboardFragment());
}
```

My `getInt("not_id", 0)` always returns 0. I have checked what the Bundle equals and this is what the logcat displays

Service

```
02-04 15:10:48.628: I/System.out(11835): Pending intent extras: Bundle[{message=New 
Voicemail, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, not_id=1, fromNotification=true, 
android.support.content.wakelockid=1, from=123412341234}]
```

MainActivity

```
02-04 15:12:29.206: I/System.out(11835): MainActivity intent extras: Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=56]
```

Is there a reason I can only retrieve `extras.getBoolean("fromNotification")` and not `extras.getInt("not_id", 0)`?

Yes I have tried adding `not_id` like I did 'fromNotification`.

Any help will be great

AP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time you call getActivity use different requestCode

Comment: On the PendingIntent?

Comment: Could I also achieve the same result by adding a `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` flag?